# Sorting a Range of Data

Tags: vba, excel

This the code for sorting a range of data based on Column E values

```
Sub SortByLevel()

   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add  Key:=Range("E13:E528" _
    ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

   With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
      .SetRange Range("A12:L528")
      .Header = xlYes
      .MatchCase = False
      .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
      .SortMethod = xlPinYin
      .Apply
  End With

End Sub
```

Note that `B12:L12` is the range of headers. I have the impression that this can be much more simpler than that. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.
Thanks, Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this :

```
Range("A12:L528").Sort Key1:=Range("E13"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fine! If I may ask, when I have a custom list, e.g. 
'CustomOrder:= "Low, Normal, High"' , based on which I want to sort the same range of data, where am I supposed to embed it in the code you have posted? Because I get an error

Comment: must be add custom list to the sorting option like this, line 1 :   ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E13"), CustomOrder:="Low,Normal,High"  line 2 :
    Range("A12:L528").Sort Key1:=Range("E13"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes